# Cassandra parsing date

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table created using following script:

```
CREATE TABLE "TestTable2" (
    id uuid,
    timestamp timestamp,
    msg text,
    priority int,
    source text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, timestamp)
);
```

Now I'm inserting one row:

```
INSERT INTO "TestTable2" (id, timestamp, msg, source) values (uuid(), '2002-03-31 02:36:10', 'asdas dasdasd', 'system1');
```

and I get an error:

> Unable to execute CQL script on 'UdcCluster':Unable to coerce '2002-03-31 02:36:10' to a formatted date (long)

If I change the day of month to 30th or hour to 22 the statement is successfully executed.
Can you please explain to me what is wrong with the date?

PS.
Same error repeats for '1998-03-29 02:12:13', '1987-03-29 02:55:21' and '1984-03-25 02:45:25'. In all cases it's 2 am at the ending of March...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get from a specific local time to a DateTime instance and you want that to be robust against daylight savings.

Specify the timezone in the pattern: yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ssZ

> where Z is the RFC-822 4-digit time zone, expressing the time zone's
> difference from UTC. For example, for the date and time of Jan 2,
> 2003, at 04:05:00 AM, GMT:
>
> If no time zone is specified, the time zone of the Cassandra
> coordinator node handing the write request is used. For accuracy,
> DataStax recommends specifying the time zone rather than relying on
> the time zone configured on the Cassandra nodes.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html